# Is there a withLatestFrom Equivalent with Coroutines Flow?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I'm a developer who's coming from RxJava and is trying to get into coroutines.  RxJava has a couple of extremely useful operators, `withLatestFrom`, `throttleFirst`, etc. and I can't seem to find an equivalent in coroutines `Flow`.  Is there an equivalent or some other idiomatic way of achieving the same result as those RxJava operators?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. There are a lot of other missing operators but that was a deliberate decision. Only the basic ones were provided. There's a [flow extensions library](https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions) but doesn't contain a withLatestFrom yet.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1498